# react-native-network-info can't catch ip on ios device

Tags: react-native

I had used it for several month, but nowadays i can't catch IP address on iPhone and just got 'error'.  I don't know why.  Do you know?

```
NetworkInfo.getIPAddress(ip => {
  console.log(ip);
}
```

console.log => error

my react-native version: 0.37.

Comment: sorry for my format,  This is the first question I ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading to react-native 0.40.  If this isn't possible, create an [issue in Github](https://github.com/pusherman/react-native-network-info/issues).

I'm the maintainer of react-native-network-info-- it'll be easier to debug in Github since I don't have an exact answer yet.